# Create pandas column from different time serie

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have an indicator in a stored in a dataframe with a 1 hour time serie, and I'd like to extract it to a dataframe with a 1 min time serie, but I would like this indicator to have a value for each possible index of the one minute array, instead of every hour.

I tried the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime 

DAX_H1 = pd.read_csv("D:\Finance python\Data\DAX\GER30_H1_fixed.csv",index_col='date',error_bad_lines=False)
DAX_M1 = pd.read_csv("D:\Finance python\Data\DAX\GER30_m1_fixed.csv",index_col='date',error_bad_lines=False)

DAX_M1=DAX_M1.iloc[0:6000]
DAX_H1=DAX_H1.iloc[0:110]

DAX_H1["EWMA_8"]=DAX_H1["Open"].ewm(min_periods=8,com=3.5).mean()

DAX_H1.index =pd.to_datetime(DAX_H1.index)

DAX_M1.index =pd.to_datetime(DAX_M1.index)

DAX_M1["H1_EWMA_8"]=""

for i in DAX_M1.index:
    DAX_M1["H1_EWMA_8"][i] = DAX_H1["EWMA_8"][pd.Timestamp(datetime.datetime(i.year,i.month,i.day,i.hour))]
```

However, it doesn't seem to work, and even if it worked, I'd assume it would be very slow.

If I simply do the following:

`DAX_M1["H1_EWMA_8"]=DAX_H1["EWMA_8"]`

I don't have a value for `"H1_EWMA_8"` for each index:

```
2014-01-02 16:53:00            NaN
2014-01-02 16:54:00            NaN
2014-01-02 16:55:00            NaN
2014-01-02 16:56:00            NaN
2014-01-02 16:57:00            NaN
2014-01-02 16:58:00            NaN
2014-01-02 16:59:00            NaN
2014-01-02 17:00:00    9449.979026
2014-01-02 17:01:00            NaN
2014-01-02 17:02:00            NaN
Name: H1_EWMA_8, dtype: float64
```

Is there a simple way to replace the NaN value with the last available value of `"H1_EWMA_8"`?

Some part of DAX_M1 and DAX_H1 for illustration purposes:

**DAX_M1**:

```
                     Open  High   Low  Close  Total Ticks
date                                                     
2014-01-01 22:00:00  9597  9597  9597   9597            1
2014-01-02 07:05:00  9597  9619  9597   9618           18
2014-01-02 07:06:00  9618  9621  9617   9621            5
2014-01-02 07:07:00  9621  9623  9620   9623            6
2014-01-02 07:08:00  9623  9625  9623   9625            9
2014-01-02 07:09:00  9625  9625  9622   9623            6
2014-01-02 07:10:00  9623  9625  9622   9624           13
2014-01-02 07:11:00  9624  9626  9624   9626            8
2014-01-02 07:12:00  9626  9626  9623   9623            9
2014-01-02 07:13:00  9623  9625  9623   9625            5
```

**DAX_H1:**

```
                     Open  High   Low  Close  Total Ticks       EWMA_8
date                                                                  
2014-01-01 22:00:00  9597  9597  9597   9597            1          NaN
2014-01-02 07:00:00  9597  9626  9597   9607          322          NaN
2014-01-02 08:00:00  9607  9617  9510   9535         1730          NaN
2014-01-02 09:00:00  9535  9537  9465   9488         1428          NaN
2014-01-02 10:00:00  9488  9505  9478   9490          637          NaN
2014-01-02 11:00:00  9490  9512  9473   9496          817          NaN
2014-01-02 12:00:00  9496  9510  9495   9504          450          NaN
2014-01-02 13:00:00  9504  9514  9484   9484          547  9518.123073
2014-01-02 14:00:00  9484  9493  9424   9436         1497  9509.658500
```

Any help would be gladly appreciated!

**Edit:** This solution worked:

```
DAX_M1 = DAX_M1.fillna(method='ffill')
```

Comment: There's a [`bfill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.bfill.html) method, not sure if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: It actually does the trick, thank you very much :)